# Current Fern Taxonomy

Tags: botany, taxonomy, plant-anatomy

In our school, the manual exhibits an outdated taxonomy as expressed by my teacher. We're following the Kingdom Plantae, Division Pterophyta, then divided into three Orders:

1. Order Filicales
2. Order Ophogossum
3. Order Marattiales

However, I tried to look up what is the currently accepted taxonomy for ferns. What phylum is it under? Are its children taxa changed drastically? Does it still have a taxon dedicated to ferns only? What are also the morphological differences eyed in classifying these plants? These are some of the confusions I have. Thank you for answering :)